# How do you duplicate multiple entries in MySQL using a Temporary Table?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, duplicates

My Database has assessments, questions, and question_items tables.
assessments have 0-many questions, and questions have 0-many question_items.

I need to be able to duplicate entire assessments, which in turn also duplicates the corresponding questions and question_items.

My MySQL Database:

```
assessments table
id
name
acronym
assessment_type_id
language_id
date_created
date_updated

questions table
id 
assessment_id
order_int
question_type_id
title

question_items table
id 
question_id
question_item_type_id
order
value
option
correct_answer
multiple_answers_allowed
```

Currently I have the following MySQL code working to duplicate assessments and questions, but I do not know how to duplicate and add the question_items.

```
   CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp SELECT * from assessments WHERE id =1; ## id to duplicate
ALTER TABLE tmp drop ID;
INSERT INTO assessments SELECT 0,tmp.* FROM tmp;
SET @last_id_in_assessments = LAST_INSERT_ID();
   CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp2 SELECT * from questions WHERE assessment_id = 1;
update tmp2 set assessment_id = @last_id_in_assessments;
ALTER TABLE tmp2 drop ID;
INSERT INTO questions SELECT 0,tmp2.* FROM tmp2;
DROP TABLE tmp;
DROP TABLE tmp2;
```

I don't know how to do this because question_items doesn't have an assessment foreign key. Is it still possible to do this? I wanted to do it purely in MySQL but I can use PHP if needed.

Comment: If anyone can even offer a different way entirely to do this I would be open to it. Thanks.

Comment: Would it be better just to do this all in PHP and use MySQL just to do a bunch of inserts?